# State Equations

Tags: capacitor, current, circuit-analysis, inductor

Please can you help me in finding the state equations for the circuit below? My problem is the two capacitors. How will we cater for the second capacitor? I only know problems with 1 capacitor and 1 inductor.

Please can you help me and find my attached solution which I attempted half way through?

[image: question and my solution]

---

This is my attempt for the solution. Is it correct? (mathjax transcript below)

[image: state eqaution solution]

*editor's note: missing parts of the second equation have been added in \$\color{red}{red}\$. They reappear in subsequent equations.*
$$
\begin{align}
C_1 \frac{dv_{c1}}{dt} &= i_1 - i_L = \frac{v_s-v_{c1}}{R_1} - i_L & \text{(using KCL at node 1)}\\
    \frac{dv_{c1}}{dt} &= \color{red}{\frac{1}{C_1}} \left( \frac{v_s}{R_1} - \frac{v_{c1}}{R\color{red}{_1}} - i_L\right) & \text{(divide by }C_1\text{)}  \\
\frac{dv_{c1}}{dt} &= \frac{1}{R_1C_1}v_s - \frac{1}{R_1C_1}v_{c1} - \frac{1}{C_1}i_L\\
\frac{dv_{c1}}{dt} &=  - \frac{1}{R_1C_1}v_{c1}+\frac{1}{R_1C_1}v_s - \frac{1}{C_1}i_L\\
\\
&\text{using KVL on inductor}\\
\\
C_2 \frac{dv_{c2}}{dt} &= i_L - g_mv_{c1} & \text{(using KCL node 2)}\\
\frac{dv_{c2}}{dt} &= \frac{-g_m}{C_2}v_{c1} +  \frac{1}{C_2}i_L & \text{(dividing by }C_2\text{)}\\
\\
\\
L \frac{di_L}{dt} &= v_{c1} - v_{c2} & \text{(dividing by }L\text{)}\\
\frac{di_L}{dt} &= \frac{1}{L}v_{c1} - \frac{1}{L}v_{c2}\\
\end{align}
$$

$$
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{dv_{c1}}{dt}\\
\frac{dv_{c2}}{dt}\\
\frac{di_L}{dt}\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
=
\left[
\begin{matrix}
-\frac{1}{R_1C_1} & 0 & - \frac{1}{C_1}\\
-\frac{g_m}{C_2} & 0 & \frac{1}{C_2}\\
\frac{1}{L} & -\frac{1}{L} & 0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
\left[
\begin{matrix}
v_{c1}\\
v_{c2}\\
i_L\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
+
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\frac{1}{R_1C_1}\\
0\\
0\\
\end{matrix}
\right]
v_s
$$

Comment: Welcome on EE.SE. Please, post what have you tried. We don't give complete solutions for homeworks, unless one shows us real effort. Visit the [help] to learn about this site netiquette.

Comment: Transient or permanent?

Comment: Are you allowed to use impedance to resolve the problem?

Comment: I got much the same using charge instead of capacitor voltage. I think it's fine.